# Mirroring git repositories one-way while applying deterministic changes

Tags: git, version-control, enterprise, mirroring

I have the following external git repo:

```bash
test % git log
commit 022c4bebe111329c9b07e714c353d68d238d6187
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:13:36 2023 +0200

    first commit

test % cat README.md
# test
```

I clone it into a temp repo `test-1` and run

```bash
test-1 % git filter-branch --tree-filter '
  export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(git log -1 --format=%aI)"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -1 --format=%cI)"
  echo "// modified" >> README.md
' -- --all

test-1 % git log
commit c79e6cc1180be936358a41d8beaba99a7ce33c71 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:13:36 2023 +0200

    first commit
```

Now I change `README.md` in the original repo:

```bash
test % echo "# test-new" > README.md
test % cat README.md
# test-new
test % git add .
test % git commit -m "change"
[main f04f865] change
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
test % git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 255 bytes | 255.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/pardeike/test.git
   022c4be..f04f865  main -> main
test % git log
commit f04f865c6e546318df7256e4cd48b3bb9505a710 (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:20:06 2023 +0200

    change

commit 022c4bebe111329c9b07e714c353d68d238d6187
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:13:36 2023 +0200

    first commit
```

and I clone it afterwards into a new temp repo `test-2` and run the same modification:

```bash
test-2 % git log
commit f04f865c6e546318df7256e4cd48b3bb9505a710 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:20:06 2023 +0200

    change

commit 022c4bebe111329c9b07e714c353d68d238d6187
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:13:36 2023 +0200

    first commit

test-2 % git filter-branch --tree-filter '
  export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(git log -1 --format=%aI)"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -1 --format=%cI)"
  echo "// modified" >> README.md
' -- --all

test-2 % git log
commit 00513669b9a95db42317c6734152e7b2861b89b7 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:20:06 2023 +0200

    change

commit 6bc296719d3aa3844c1ebb352f3daf67184f0025
Author: Andreas Pardeike <andreas.pardeike@polisen.se>
Date:   Wed Mar 29 10:20:06 2023 +0200

    first commit
```

**Question:** Why is the commit hash of 'first commit' different between temp repo test-1 and test-2? I understand that they are different than the original but how do I get them to stay the same in any temp repository?

**Why:** My task is to rewrite external repositories to mirror them for in-house use where we don't have access to internet. I need to rewrite one specific file during the mirroring to point any dependency urls to our internal git repository. I do this by appending a static text snippet to the end of an existing, well known file in all repositories processed for all tags/commits. There is no risk for conflicts because those internal repositories are read-only.

Alternatively: How can I just "process newly commits" when mirroring from original to internal repositories?

Answer (score 2):

In the second repo *both* commits' author dates (and presumable their committer dates) are equal to that of the *second* commit in the original repo. This suggests that the values you `export` are wrong.  If you want to reference the currently processed commit you can do `git log -1 ... $GIT_COMMIT`. However, `--tree-filter` does not update these dates by default so in your case you don't have to do anything to tweak them.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, `git filter-branch --tree-filter` creates a stable new history with its own commit hashes but those hashes stay the same for repeated mirroring of new commits in the original repository.

So just use `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'echo "// modified" >> README.md' -- --all`

The resulting temp repository can without conflict be pushed to an internal repository without risk of conflicts.